# AsyncNotifier keeps rendering UI when I use it with ref.watch in flutter

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have AsyncNotifier and in `build` method, I initialize return value.

```
class ContractConfigViewModel extends AsyncNotifier<ContractConfigModel> {
  late final AuthenticationRepository _authRepository;

  @override
  FutureOr<ContractConfigModel> build() async {
    _authRepository = ref.read(authRepo);

    final userId = _authRepository.user!.uid;

    final adminData = await _authRepository.getAdminProfile(userId);
    final adminProfile = AdminProfileModel.fromJson(adminData!);
    if (!adminProfile.master) {
      return ContractConfigModel(
          contractType: adminProfile.contractType,
          contractName: "${adminProfile.region} ${adminProfile.smallRegion}");
    }
    return ContractConfigModel(
      contractType: adminProfile.contractType,
      contractName: adminProfile.region,
    );
  }

  void setContractType(String value) {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    final contractModel = ContractConfigModel(
      contractType: value,
      contractName: state.value!.contractName,
    );
    state = AsyncValue.data(contractModel);
  }

  void setContractName(String value) {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    final contractModel = ContractConfigModel(
      contractType: state.value!.contractType,
      contractName: value,
    );
    state = AsyncValue.data(contractModel);
  }
}

final contractConfigProvider =
    AsyncNotifierProvider<ContractConfigViewModel, ContractConfigModel>(
  () => ContractConfigViewModel(),
);
```

**ContractConfigModel**:

```
class ContractConfigModel {
  String contractType;
  String contractName;

  ContractConfigModel({
    required this.contractType,
    required this.contractName,
  });

  ContractConfigModel.empty()
      : contractType = "",
        contractName = ";";
}
```

Here, `getAdminProfile` function is function to get data from `FireStore`.

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> getAdminProfile(String uid) async {
    final doc = await _db.collection("admin").doc(uid).get();
    return doc.data()!;
  }
```

And I need values of this `ContractConfigModel` in UI.

So when I return UI from `ConsumerStatefulWidget`, I use ref.watch function to update UI, whenever this ContractConfigModel value is udpated.

```
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ref.watch(contractConfigProvider).when(
          data: (data) {
            final userContractType = data.contractType;
            final userContractName = data.contractName;
            print(userContractName);

            return FutureBuilder(

.....
```

But when I print data coming from `ref.watch(contractConfigProvider)`, it keeps printing value permanently **even though ContractConfigModel value is not updated**.

So even though I update something in this component, It is overwritten.

What causes keeps run contractConfigProvider here?

Please help me..

plus)

I get this error message

```
  ═╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    The following FirebaseException was thrown building DefaultSelectionStyle:
    [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
    The relevant error-causing widget was:
      MaterialApp
    MaterialApp:file:///Users/hayat/FlutterProjects/ProjectsFiles/onldocc_admin/lib/main.dart:47:24
    main.dart:47
    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
    #1      <anonymous closure> (http://localhost:50230/packages/riverpod/src/stack_trace.dart:9:11)
    #2      when (http://localhost:50230/packages/riverpod/src/result.dart:110:17)
    #3      get requireState (http://localhost:50230/packages/riverpod/src/framework/element.dart:200:17)
    #4      read (http://localhost:50230/packages/riverpod/src/framework/provider_base.dart:106:19)
    #5      read (http://localhost:50230/packages/riverpod/src/framework/container.dart:229:20)
    #6      read (http://localhost:50230/packages/riverpod/src/framework/element.dart:691:23)
    #7      <anonymous closure> (http://localhost:50230/packages/onldocc_admin/router.dart:19:31)
    #8      processRedirect (http://localhost:50230/packages/go_router/src/configuration.dart:432:62)
    #9      redirect (http://localhost:50230/packages/go_router/src/configuration.dart:444:14)
    #10     [_redirect] (http://localhost:50230/packages/go_router/src/parser.dart:149:10)
    #11     parseRouteInformationWithDependencies (http://localhost:50230/packages/go_router/src/parser.dart:98:7)
    #12     [_processRouteInformation] (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/router.dart:730:12)
    #13     restoreState (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/router.dart:594:7)
    #14     [_doRestore] (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/restoration.dart:912:5)
    #15     didChangeDependencies (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/restoration.dart:898:7)
    #16     didChangeDependencies (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/router.dart:669:11)
    #17     [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5132:11)
    #18     mount (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4957:5)
    #19     inflateWidget (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3964:15)
    #20     updateChild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3695:20)
    #21     performRebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5006:16)
    #22     rebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4701:7)
    #23     update (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5312:5)
    #24     updateChild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679:14)
    #25     performRebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5006:16)
    #26     rebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4701:7)
    #27     update (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5312:5)
    #28     updateChild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679:14)
    #29     performRebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5006:16)
    #30     rebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4701:7)
    #31     update (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5312:5)
    #32     updateChild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679:14)
    #33     performRebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5006:16)
    #34     rebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4701:7)
    #35     update (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5312:5)
    #36     updateChild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679:14)
    #37     performRebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5006:16)
    #38     rebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4701:7)
    #39     update (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5057:5)
    #40     updateChild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679:14)
    #41     performRebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5006:16)
    #42     rebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4701:7)
    #43     update (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5312:5)
    #44     updateChild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679:14)
    #45     performRebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5006:16)
    #46     rebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4701:7)
    #47     update (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5057:5)
    #48     updateChild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679:14)
    #49     performRebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5006:16)
    #50     performRebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5146:11)
    #51     rebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4701:7)
    #52     update (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5169:5)
    #53     updateChild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679:14)
    #54     performRebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5006:16)
    #55     rebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4701:7)
    #56     update (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5312:5)
    
    ....
    #693    rebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4701:7)
    #694    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4963:5)
    #695    mount (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4957:5)
    #696    inflateWidget (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3964:15)
    #697    updateChild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:18)
    #698    performRebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5006:16)
    #699    rebuild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4701:7)
    #700    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4963:5)
    #701    mount (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4957:5)
    #702    inflateWidget (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3964:15)
    #703    updateChild (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:18)
    #704    [_rebuild] (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1195:16)
    #705    mount (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1164:5)
    #706    <anonymous closure> (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1111:16)
    #707    buildScope (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2713:19)
    #708    attachToRenderTree (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1110:12)
    #709    attachRootWidget (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:943:24)
    #710    <anonymous closure> (http://localhost:50230/packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:924:7)
    #711    internalCallback (http://localhost:50230/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/isolate_helper.dart:48:19)
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: do you have a method to update your `ContractConfigModel` state in the `ContractConfigViewModel` class?

Comment: @Ruble yes I have, I add full code above, But I update state only when it is needed. but this keeps rendering

Comment: Is your ` FutureOr<ContractConfigModel> build()` method being called over and over again? Checked?

Comment: @Ruble no bulid method is not called over and over, it runs only once.

Comment: what is your `ContractConfigModel`? Seems to be the problem...

Comment: @Ruble I add that also above on post, thanks for your help, I've struggled with this problem all day

Comment: @Ruble If you're okay, I can open discussion

Comment: is it possible to solve the Firebase initialization issue first? you need to add `await Firebase.initializeApp(...)` in your `main.dart` file. You can use flutterfire cli to make it kinda easier to manage.

Comment: i would also suggest to make the `ContractConfigModel` fields immutable or even use @freezed

Comment: @brightknight08 I did that, -> `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
    await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      ],
    );`

Comment: @brightknight08 sometimes i update  `ContractConfigModel`, even so, is it okay to make it immutable?

Comment: if you make `ContractConfigModel` immutable, you will need to use the setters in your asyncnotifier (ie., `setContractName`, etc.). btw, you can use the package `freezed` to easily make it immutable, or use a code generator to make a `.copyWith(...)` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your `ContractConfigModel` immutable -- all fields must be `final` and the constructor `const`. This should solve your issue.

Also, consider using [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) to easily change your model via `copyWith`.

Comment: exactly. like my comment on the post.